# how to retrive all the document in sub document array and if there is any duplicates of field how to retrive the latest one?

Tags: mongodb, duplicates, subdocument

i am having db structure like this below.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("53770b9de4b0ba6f4c976a27"),
    "source": [{
        "value": 5127,
        "createdAt": ISODate("2014-05-7T07:11:00Z"),
        "generated": ISODate("2014-05-17T07:23:00Z"),
    }, {
        "value": 5187,
        "createdAt": ISODate("2014-05-17T07:39:00Z"),
        "generated": ISODate("2014-05-17T07:40:00Z"),
    }, {
        "value": 5187,
        "createdAt": ISODate("2014-05-17T07:39:00Z"),
        "generated": ISODate("2014-05-17T07:41:00Z")
    }],
}
```

In this there is a duplicate in the subdocument array.I need to write the mongo db query to retrive all the sub - document and if there is any duplicates then based on the "generated"
values i need to rerive the latest on like below.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("53770b9de4b0ba6f4c976a27"),
    "source": [{
        "value": 5127,
        "createdAt": ISODate("2014-05-17T07:11:00Z"),
    }, {
        "value": 5187,
        "createdAt": ISODate("2014-05-17T07:39:00Z"),
        "generated": ISODate("2014-05-17T07:41:00Z")

    }],

}
```

Is there any way to get the data like using mongo db query?

Comment: please remember to format your code (which I've done this time. edit your post to see how it works) so that anyone else can read your post easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) you can finish the job.

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$source'},
    {$group: {_id: {value: "$source.value", createdAt: "$source.createdAt"}, generated: {$max: "$source.generated"}}}
]);
```

Which gives you the result:

```
{ "_id" : { "value" : 5187, "createdAt" : ISODate("2014-05-17T07:39:00Z") }, "generated" : ISODate("2014-05-17T07:41:00Z") }
{ "_id" : { "value" : 5127, "createdAt" : ISODate("2014-05-07T07:11:00Z") }, "generated" : ISODate("2014-05-17T07:23:00Z") }
```

A little bit different from what you want. But if you really want the format above, try this:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$source'},
    {$group: {_id: {_id: "$_id", value: "$source.value", createdAt: "$source.createdAt"}, generated: {$max: "$source.generated"}}},
    {$group: {_id: "$_id._id", source: {$push: {value: "$_id.value", createdAt: "$_id.createdAt", generated: "$generated"}}}}
]);
```

which gives you:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("53770b9de4b0ba6f4c976a27"),
    "source": [{
        "value": 5187,
        "createdAt": ISODate("2014-05-17T07:39:00Z"),
        "generated": ISODate("2014-05-17T07:41:00Z")
    }, {
        "value": 5127,
        "createdAt": ISODate("2014-05-07T07:11:00Z"),
        "generated": ISODate("2014-05-17T07:23:00Z")
    }]
}
```